# Criteria for irrationality of Euler's constant

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Define for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$I_n=\int_0^1\int_0^1 -\frac{(x(1-x)y(1-y))^n}{(1-xy)\log xy}dx dy$$

In [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-11/S0002-9939-03-07081-3/S0002-9939-03-07081-3.pdf) it is proved that
$$I_n=\binom{2n}{n}\gamma+L_n-A_n$$ where $L_n=d^{-1}_{2n}\log S_n$, $A_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2 H_{n+i}$ and $$S_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{\min(k-1,n-k)}\prod_{j=i+1}^{n-i}(n+k)^{\frac{2d_{2n}}{j}\binom{n}{i}^2}$$ where $d_n=\text{lcm}(1,2,...,n)$ and $H_n$ is the $n$th Harmonic number.

In Theorem $4$ it is proved using the above representation of $I_n$ that for $n$ fixed, $\{\log S_n\}=d_{2n}I_n$ if and only if $\gamma=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $q|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$ and $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

> **Question:** Can we conclude that for $n$ fixed, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is rational?

We have by multiplication by $d_{2n}$
$$d_{2n}I_n=d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma+d_{2n}L_n-d_{2n}A_n$$ which can be rewritten as $$\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n=d_{2n}A_n- d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma$$ where $d_{2n}A_n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So we have, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma=a/b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $b|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$. Can we conclude that for $n$ fixed, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is rational?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit** I am looking for an answer which I can accept. Thank you.

Comment: $\{x\} = \{y\}$ is equivalent to $x - y \in \mathbb Z$ for $x, y \in \mathbb R$. In the forward direction we get $x - y = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}  - \lfloor y \rfloor - \{y\} = (\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor) \in \mathbb Z$, and in the backward direction we get $\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\} -  \lfloor y\rfloor - \{y\} = n$, i.e. $ \{x\} -\{y\} = n -   \lfloor x \rfloor +  \lfloor y \rfloor \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Looking at your problem, you are equivalently then asking if $d_{2n}I_n = \{d_{2n}I_n\}$, i.e. if $d_{2n}I_n \in [0,1)$, which is indeed true (as mentioned in the paper, we have $d_{2n}I_n \in (0,1)$ by Lemma 3), so your restatement of the problem is correct.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks. Please write as an answer. Please give the details.

Comment: Is this really a good starting point for establishing whether or not the Euler-Mascheroni constant is irrational, with convergents that are not only irrational, but transcendental? Personally I think it is worth spending time first searching for and constructing a unit square integral (even if contrived or unwieldy) with rational convergents to the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the claim

> for $n$ fixed, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q|d_{2n}{2n\choose n}$.

provides a partial answer to your question as follows.

**Proposition.** The following conditions are equivalent:

(1) $\gamma$ is irrational;

(2) $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for each natural $n$;

(3) $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for infinitely many natural $n$.

*Proof.* The implication $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ directly follows from the claim.

The implication $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$ is trivial.

$(3)\Rightarrow (1)$ Suppose for a contradiction that $\gamma=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb N$. Pick any $n\ge q/2$. Then $q|d_{2n}|d_{2n}{2n\choose n}$, so $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: (+$1$). So, if $\gamma$ is irrational ( is this a typo? Should it be $\gamma$ is rational) then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$. Don't we need the condition $b|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$?
Conversely, if $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$ then $\gamma$ is irrational (again is this a typo? Should it be $\gamma$ is rational). Don't we need the condition $b|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But the other answer claims that the condition is not necessary and sufficient. Can you please prove your claim.

Comment: @Max Sorry for misprints and thanks for noticing. I'll try to add some arguments to the answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you. You wrote, Conversely, if $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$ then $\gamma$ is irrational. In fact, if $\gamma=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb N$ and $n\ge q/2$ then $q|d_{2n}|d_{2n}{2n\choose n}$, so $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Does this suffice? What happens in other case of $\gamma=p/q$ and $n<q/2$?

Comment: @Max It depends. Let $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$. Then the issue is to provide $q|d_{2n}{2n\choose n}$. If this is provided then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, if this is not provided then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. So, if $\gamma$ is irrational then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$
Also conversely, if $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$ then $\gamma$ is irrational. This is true because if $n\geq q/2$, then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ which is a contradiction ( since we are given that $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$). Can we combine these two statements into a single statement?

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what is a if and only if statement for irrationality of $\gamma$?

Comment: @Max In Proposition are two such statements, namely, (2) and (3).

Answer (score 2):

> So we have, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma=a/b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $b|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$. Can we conclude that for $n$ fixed, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is rational?

If I understand what you wrote correctly, you have already proved that $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma=a/b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $b|d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}$.

So, I think the answer to your question is No.

We can say that
$$\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\in\mathbb Z\implies \text{$\gamma$ is rational}$$
since
$$\begin{align}&\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\in\mathbb Z
\\\\&\implies d_{2n}A_n- d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma\in\mathbb Z
\\\\&\implies \underbrace{d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}}_{\text{a positive integer}}\gamma\in\mathbb Z
\\\\&\implies \text{$\gamma$ is rational}\end{align}$$

However, it is not true that
$$\text{$\gamma$ is rational}\implies \log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\in\mathbb Z$$

If $\gamma$ is rational such that $d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma$ is not an integer, then $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n$ is not an integer since
$$\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n=\underbrace{d_{2n}A_n}_{\text{integer}}- \underbrace{d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma}_{\text{not integer}}$$

---

**Added** :

- It is true that if $\gamma$ is irrational, then $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$ for each natural $n$.
- It is true that if $\log S_n−d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$ for each natural $n$, then $\gamma$ is irrational. The reason is as follows. For any integer $b$ such that $\gamma=\frac ab$, there is $n$ such that $b\mid d_{2n}$. So, for such an $n$, $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\in\mathbb Z$.

**Added 2** :

We can say that $\gamma$ is irrational if and only if $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$ for each natural $n$.

Comment: ($+1$). Thanks. Can we say that if $\gamma$ is irrational then $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$. And,
Conversely, if $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for *each* natural $n$ then $\gamma$ is irrational?

Comment: Can we say the latter by adding the condition that $d_{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\gamma$ is an integer or some other condition?

Comment: Can you please combine the two statements in your "added" part into a single statement ?

Comment: Thanks. But $\gamma$ is a constant. How can it depend on $n$?

Comment: So can we say for each natural $n$, $\log S_n-d_{2n} I_n \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is irrational?

Comment: @Max : It depends on $\gamma$. If $\gamma=\frac 12$, then $\log S_1-d_2I_1\in\mathbb Z$. But if $\gamma=\frac 15$, then $\log S_1-d_2I_1\not\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think, my statement was equivalent to your statement that "$\gamma$ is irrational if and only if $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$ for each natural $n$". Is it not?

Comment: @Max : It is true that $\gamma$ is irrational if and only if "$\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$ for each natural $n$", but I don't think that it is true that for each natural $n$, "$\gamma$ is irrational if and only if $\log S_n-d_{2n}I_n\not\in\mathbb Z$". In the former, I interpreted "each" as "every", sorry if I misunderstood you.